# Discord.js ts1381

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const { GuildMember } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'bans members',
    args: true,
    execute(message, args) {
        const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
            return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to kick them!');
        }
        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('716621849412370453')){
            <guild>.members.ban(user);
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`Ты не можешь кикать участников, ${message.author}!`)
        }
    },
};
```

Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?
Please, help me. I don't know how to correct this error

Comment: Which line/offset does the error tell you ? Is that `<guild>` legit ? seems not to me

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to have a few syntax errors.

`<guild>.members.ban(user);` is producing these errors because `<guild>` is incorrect syntax and `user` is undefined.

Resulting Code:

```js
const { GuildMember } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'bans members',
    args: true,
    execute(message, args) {
        const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
            return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to kick them!');
        }
        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('716621849412370453')){
            message.guild.members.ban(taggedUser);
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`Ты не можешь кикать участников, ${message.author}!`)
        }
    },
};
```